# awk with tabulation as delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the following output

```
root@root# adsl info --state|grep "Upstream rate"
Max:    Upstream rate = 1120 Kbps, Downstream rate = 8948 Kbps
Bearer: 0, Upstream rate = 1021 Kbps, Downstream rate = 4095 Kbps
```

The tabulation in the above output are present in

```
root@root# adsl info --state|grep "Upstream rate"
Max:<TAB>Upstream rate = 1120 Kbps, Downstream rate = 8948 Kbps
Bearer:<TAB>0, Upstream rate = 1021 Kbps, Downstream rate = 4095 Kbps
```

I want to parse the above output with awk. the delimeters are tabulation and `,`

So I tried

```
adsl info --state|grep "Upstream rate"| awk -F'[ ,]' '{ print $1}'
```

but it returns

```
Max:    Upstream
Bearer: 0
```

Even

```
adsl info --state|grep "Upstream rate"| awk -F'[\t,]' '{ print $1}'
```

returns

```
Max:    Ups
Bearer: 0
```

I expected:

```
Max:
Bearer:
```

I think I have to add tabulation delimiter in the `-F` option. How to do that?

Comment: A simple `awk '{print $1}'` will does this job.

Comment: When you say `the delimeters are tabulation and ,` do you mean that a string that is a tab followed or preceded by a comma is a delimiter, or do you mean that a tab OR a comma is a delimiter or something else? It'd help if you post a version of your input with the tab characters replaced with "<tab>" or something to clarify.

Comment: @AvinashRaj print $1 was just an example I want to parse other fields

Comment: @MOHAMED then update your question to show a more interesting/meaningful example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EdMorton I think my question at the end is simple. How to add the tabulation in the `-F` option? that's all

Comment: OK, just add it -F'[\t,]'. You don't need grep+awk by the way.

Comment: @EdMorton `-F'[\t,]'` does not work

Comment: Ah the famous "it does not work". OK - how do you suggest we proceed from here? I have no more information on what you want to do or in what way it's failing, do you?

Comment: @EdMorton I updated my question, I added the output of `-F'[\t,]'`

Comment: Your input is not as you've told us. There is no tab between `Max:` and `Upstream`, there may be a tab between `Ups` and `tream`, and you may have spurious control characters in your input. Run `cat -v` on your input to see.

Comment: The alternative is that the `\t` in your FS is being treated as a plain `t`. See my answer for how to proceed to debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input were as you've told us, with the first white space in each line a tab character, this is what you would have for tab-or-comma separated fields:

```
$ awk -F'[\t,]' '{print "$0 =",$0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "\t$"i,"=",$i}' file
$0 = Max:       Upstream rate = 1120 Kbps, Downstream rate = 8948 Kbps
        $1 = Max:
        $2 = Upstream rate = 1120 Kbps
        $3 =  Downstream rate = 8948 Kbps
$0 = Bearer:    0, Upstream rate = 1021 Kbps, Downstream rate = 4095 Kbps
        $1 = Bearer:
        $2 = 0
        $3 =  Upstream rate = 1021 Kbps
        $4 =  Downstream rate = 4095 Kbps
```

Run the above command on your input and post the results. The alternative to your input not being as you've stated is that the `\t` in your FS is being treated as just a plain `t`. I can't imagine what would cause that (unless maybe you're running all of this under ssh or something that's interpreting the backslash before it gets to awk?) but you need to find out which problem you have to make progress and running the above command along with a `cat -v` of your input will tell you exactly what the problem is.

I'm wondering if your awk is broken, given you're getting tools from busy box and I've no idea what their awk supports. Try this:

```
$ awk -F'['$'\t'',]' '{print "$0 =",$0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "\t$" i, "=", $i}' file
```

It will use a literal tab character in the FS - maybe that will make a difference.

Comment: my cat is limited it's from busy box it does not contain the -v option

Comment: Try `catv` instead of `cat -v`.

Comment: Did you try the awk command I suggested at the end of my answer above? If that doesn't help, I'm afraid you're on your own as there;s no point me trying to guess what tools are/aren't present on "busy box" and which may or may not function as typically expected.